# Update hawtio in Jboss Fuse 6.3

Tags: java, jboss, jbossfuse, hawtio, jboss-esb

How to update hawtio in Jboss Fuse 6.3? I would like install latest version hawtio with support proxyWhitelist.

Comment: @larsgrefer nothing, because I can't find information about this process in Jboss Documentation and Hawtio Documentation. And... I'm new in Jboss and java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a Red Hat subscription for JBoss Fuse?  Then you should be able to get Fuse 6.3 roll-up patches. The proxyWhitelist support for hawtio is included in the 6.3 R4 roll-up patch. As Kevin Boone pointed out, it's already available.

Answer (score 1):

6.3 patch Rollup 4 has now been released.

I feel obliged to point out that Red Hat will not have tested any version of Hawtio in Fuse other than the one shipped with the distribution or an official patch. Plugging in a different Hawtio version will put your Fuse installation into an untested state.